# TSQL: how change row situated before another row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table in a SQL Server database (is only a fragment of the table,and it show only the rows with the same ID = 290 for example ) :

```
ID_Mov |TypeRow|CodeArticle      | Description                  | Price
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 290   | 1     | 00311-CC71671   | Aprilia                      | 100,00
 290   | 8     |                 | this row contain only note   |   0,00
 290   | 1     | APRSV1408-013SU | Air Box                      |   0,00
 290   | 1     | APRSV1408-018SU | Ammortizzatore               |   0,00
 290   | 1     | APRSV1408-1237U | Antenna                      |   0,00
```

I want to put the price of the rows AFTER typerow 8 to 50,and the row BEFORE typerow 8 to 0.

So the result must be:

```
290 |1 |00311-CC71671  |Aprilia                   |0,00
290 |8 |               |this row contain only note|0,00
290 |1 |APRSV1408-013SU|Air Box                   |50,00
290 |1 |APRSV1408-018SU|Ammortizzatore            |50,00
290 |1 |APRSV1408-1237U|Antenna                   |50,00
```

Comment: Is there any other columns in your table? I am asking because there should be a way to define which rows are inserted/located after row with `TypeRow` column `8` and each before. Only if you have such column (date/id) you can have deterministic results.

Comment: I am a little confused. Do you wish to set the price to 0 when the TypeRow ranges from 8 to 50 and also set the price to 0 for TypeRow 7 or less? Your example does not show this.

Comment: There is not others colums in the table ; I want to set the price =0 in the row that is previous the row with type=8 ,and to set the price =50 in the row that follow the type = 8. Only type 8 and 1 exist in the table.

Comment: @gotqn is right, you need the table to be sorted in some way, otherwise "before" and "after" have no meaning. Is there a primary key on the table?

Comment: As already stated, you must define the order of rows based on an exsiting column in your table. If you don't have a column like this then you'd better come up with one quickly.

Comment: In relational databases there is no such thing as an implicit order and in this case SQL Server is free to return rows in any order depending upon the queryplan unless you have specified an ORDER BY clause. I cannot see how you can reliably achieve what you need unless you have a column on whcih you can order such as a datetime field or an identity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your problem is not going to be solved with this approach, but:-

```
 update this_table set price=50 
 where id_mov=290 and type_row=1 and price=0

 update this_table set price=0 
 where id_mov=290 and type_row=1 and price=100
```

will produce the result you have asked for.

If you explained how the new price of 50 is derived, a more generic solution that would deal with the other rows in the table could be suggested.

This does it in one pass:-

```
 update this_table set price=case price when 0 then 50 when 100 then 0 end
 where id_mov=290 and type_row=1
```